# Google Drive API - Port Number?

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way to specify port number for redirect URIs for API access, specifically for Google Drive? I can type in, for example, `https://localhost:8443/some-servlet` but not `https://my-server:8443/some-servlet`. Is there a reason this is not allowed? Also, is there a workaround?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a valid domain for your URL. Both `https://localhost:8443/some-servlet` and `https://www.example.com:8443/some-servlet` are accepted, so perhaps you should use `https://my-server.mydomain.com:8443/some-servlet`.

Comment: Thanks, Claudio. So, basically there's no way to specify the url without the domain name? I can do so in Salesforce and Dropbox, so I'm not sure why Google wouldn't allow it in their API. TIA